# How to send a PUT request with payload using POST or GET?

Tags: javascript, tizen-web-app, philips-hue

I need to send a PUT request with a payload to an API (Philips Hue Bridge), but I have some limitations in javascript. 
I can **only** use:

## XMLHttpRequest methods:

`open(method, url [, async = true [, username = null [, password = null]]])`

*Sets the request method, request URL, and synchronous flag.
**Supported request method : GET, POST***

`send(data = null)`

*Initiates the request. The optional 'data' argument allows only UTF-8 encoded string type. The argument is ignored if request method is GET.*

`abort()`

*Cancels any network activity.*

This limitation comes from the [Tizen Wearable Web Widget Specification](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/wearable_widget/web_widget.html)

## Philips Hue Bridge API expects:

**URL:** `http://hostname/api/username/lights/lightKey/state`

**Method:** `PUT`

**Payload example:** `{"on": true}`

## What I tried:

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

`xhr.open('GET', 'http://hostname/api/username/lights/lightLey/state?on=true');`

`xhr.send();`

**Response:** `400 (Bad request)`

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`

`xhr.open('POST', 'http://hostname/api/username/lights/lightLey/state?on=true');`

`xhr.send();`

**Response:** `400 (Bad request)`

Also tried `GET` and `POST` with following URL endings:

`../state?{on=true}`

`../state?{on:true}`

`../state?{"on"=true}`

`../state?{"on":true}`

**Response:** `400 (Bad request)`

Again, I cannot use any additional libraries or commands besides the XMLHttpRequest methods mentioned above.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you tell us what technologies/frameworks you're using?

Comment: Good point! Edited the question to include a pointer to "Tizen Wearable Web Widget Specification".

Comment: Based on their documentation - you can not do a PUT request. They've limited their implementation of XMLHttoRequest. You could create a server your self, POST from the app to the server, and then let the server do the PUT for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought there might be a way to emulate a PUT by using POST or GET, manipulating the URL or something... it's quite a bummer. I thought about a proxy server but it's not viable for the small app Im writing.

Answer (score 1):

below is the sample code. you can try this way in your code.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'your_URL.php';
var params = 'on=true';
http.open('PUT', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: I **cannot** use PUT. See description.

Comment: If you can't use PUT in your code, then you can't use the Hue Bridge PUT endpoint. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `method` property to `PUT` should do the trick.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('PUT', 'http://hostname/api/username/lights/lightLey/state?on=true');
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I **cannot** use PUT. See description.

Comment: Did you actually try it? XMLHttpRequest is fully able to send a PUT request.

Comment: Yes I did. I get the following error ```E/StarFish( 7115): Unsupported method : put```. This output is from a tizen watch emulator.